# How do I synchronize Firebase Storage and Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have yet to find any good documentation to tell me how to manage this issue. Is there any guidance someone can reference for this issue?

For an Android app, I have started using Google Firebase Storage along with my realtime Database, and I have a question on how to ensure file uploads and database updates happen in the proper order.

Previously, I was encoding an audio file to a string and uploading it to FB Database along with other related data as a single hash map to ensure consistency. The related data that is being stored is a POJO relating to what users can access the audio, the path where the audio is stored in the database, and more.

My new set up is first to upload the audio file to FB Storage, and, once the file is uploaded, trigger a FB Database update for the related data. Once the database listener indicates completion, the app moves to a different activity.

I am concerned that this two step process is unstable (user leaves the activity before both tasks are done, Storage upload is interrupted and Database update never occurs, etc.). If the Database information isn't updated, the other users won't be notified that the audio file is online and they won't have the path to reference it stored in the database.

What is the proper order for structuring simultaneous Storage and Database uploads in the new Google Firebase?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you are storing and what would happen if they are not in-sync?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the text above--The stored data is a POJO that tracks who has access to the file, what user uploaded it, what the file path is. It is also used to notify certain users that a file has been uploaded that they can access. If the file is uploaded but the database isn't updated, the file path to the audio file could be lost and the app would lose track of where it was in the sequence of which user uploads the next file.

Comment: Hi all, I have yet to find any good documentation to tell me how to manage this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You may [edit] your question to bump it to the top of the front page. Your comment only replies to me.

Comment: Ah. That's how it works. Details, details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why there are no solid answers for this yet. Anyway, I have faced very similar problems and eventually resorted with nested-updates using completion blocks (exactly how you described in your question).

Very recently, Firebase introduced cloud functions. I am utilizing this to watch the files that are uploaded, and then create a metadata entry into FB Database with the cloud function.

Basically, I use childByAutoId() to generate a key which is used to name the file. For example, profile pictures are saved at "gs://*bucket-id*/profile_pictures/*somerandomkey*.jpeg". Then I create a metadata entry into my FB database with cloud functions by utilizing the key from the filename.

I am not sure if there is a better way, but using cloud functions surely seems like a better approach than the nested-updates approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload image using Firebase Storage, in success you get a downloadable URL of that image. Then put all the values in the custom object including that image URL and save that object in RealTime Database of Firebase.
And you can use the image URL by retrieving object from RealTime Database.